# Segmentation fault when exiting QApplication

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault, qt5, pyside2

Tested on:

- **OS**: Arch Linux (Linux 5.15.2-arch1-1)
- **Python**: 3.9.7
- **PySide2**: 5.15.2
- **Shiboken**: 5.15.2

When exiting my application, I got an address boundary error.

GDB output:

```
...
Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7d0ae59 in _PyObject_GC_NewVar () from /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7d0ae59 in _PyObject_GC_NewVar () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#1  0x00007ffff7d0e2d8 in PyTuple_Pack () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#2  0x00007ffff7dd82d1 in _PyErr_SetKeyError () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#3  0x00007ffff7d1655a in _PyDict_DelItem_KnownHash () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#4  0x00007ffff7d088e1 in  () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#5  0x00007ffff6c1e260 in Shiboken::String::finalizeStaticStrings() () at /home/sati/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shiboken2/libshiboken2.abi3.so.5.15
#6  0x00007ffff7c89016 in  () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#7  0x00007ffff7df4cfa in Py_RunMain () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#8  0x00007ffff7dc5ab9 in Py_BytesMain () at /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0
#9  0x00007ffff7a50b25 in __libc_start_main () at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#10 0x000055555555504e in _start ()
```

**Example code**

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()
window.show()
window.resize(600,400)

myApp.exec_()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: @ekhumoro, the example doesn't really matter here. This error occurs even with the simpliest code. (As in the updated post)

Comment: It certainly does matter, because your previous example included several modules and files that weren't included. But anyway, the current example does not segfault for me, when using arch linux with the official packages. From the traceback, it seems you are using a local build of libshiboken, which is probably the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ekhumoro said, the problem was in `shiboken2` from Pip. I removed packages and installed ones from Arch Linux repositories.

```sh
pip uninstall shiboken2
pip uninstall PySide2
sudo pacman -Sy pyside2 shiboken2
```